# Не работает сохранение из base64 в изображение

Tags: ruby

Есть base64 строка.

```
`data:image/jpeg;base64,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`
```

В любых онлайн чекерах он мне показывает норм изображение, однако когда я сохраняю его через руби файл не открывается.

```
File.open("/home/user/22.jpeg", 'wb') do|f| 
  f.write(Base64.decode64(base64)) 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Это не совсем [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

> Используются только символы латинского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре — символы (A—Z, a—z), цифры (0—9), и символы «+» и «/», с символом «=» в качестве специального кода суффикса.

Выдают символы `,`, `:` и `;`. Да и если использовать вместо `decode64` метод `strict_decode64`, вы получите `ArgumentError`.

На самом деле это [**data URI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), содержащий не только сами данные, но также их тип (content type) и способ кодирования (который может быть и не base64!).

Уже существует достаточно элегантный адаптер для стандартной библиотеки, [гем `data_uri`](https://github.com/dball/data_uri), который позволяет разбить этот URI на компоненты "в чистом виде":

```
require "data_uri"
uri = URI(ваша_строка)
File.write('sample.jpg', uri.data)
```

Но в данном конкретном случае внутри происходит нечто очень простое, эквивалентное:

```
base64 = ваша_строка.split(',').last # в base64 не бывает запятых, так что это безопасно
data = Base64.strict_decode64(base64)
File.write('sample.jpg', data)
```